# Bootstrap Header not using CSS font family

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web design, html and css, but found bootstrap to be workable with my experience. My problem is that I can't figure out why my font-family is not getting picked up by my Header. I have loaded the Google fonts html code and added the font-family CSS to just about everywhere I can think of without any changes getting picked up by the html code. I want the whole header, but only the header to use Cantarell.

This is the code in my head as provided by Google

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantarell|Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
          <li class="list-img"><a href="/index.html"><img src="wildfly.png" alt=" "></a></li>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/aboutme.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">DROPDOWN<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/pineisland.html">Pine Island</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
        <li class="navbar-link"><a rel="author" href="#" target="_blank">CAPT&#039;S BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="/media.html">MEDIA</a></li>
    <li><a href="/rates.html">RATES</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" target="_top"><span itemprop="email">##</a></li>
    <li class="number">| 123.123.1234</li>
      </ul>



.navbar li, p, a:link, a:visited {
display: inline;
font-size: 15px;
text-decoration:none;
color: #898989;
font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif;
}

.navbar li a:hover,ul#nav li.selected {
color:  #FFF ;
font-weight: bold;
 }

 .navbar-link  a:visited {
color: #898989;
}

 .navbar li.active a {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: underline;
font-size:16px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 10px;
 }

.navbar img {   
height: 65px;
 }

.navbar li.number {
color: #BFBFBF;
font-size:20px;
font-style:italic;
} 

.number {
text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:9px
}

 .navbar-collapse {
padding-top: 7px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;

 }

 .navbar-right {
color: #BFBFBF;
padding: 5px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-transform: none;
}
```

I am new to coding websites as this is my first one, but would appreciate any help!

Comment: According to the code you posted above, the Google fonts are working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8rmLq68u/. Are you sure the link to Google Fonts is in the correct place i.e. inside the <head></head> area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add font-family: 'Cantarell'; to your body class.  add your own style sheet e.g. all.css (be sure to call it in your head) and add in...

```
body { font-family: 'Cantarell'; }
```

Comment: The css i have provided is from a separate style sheet . Are you saying thatI need to add it to the body and then call it again in the header selection ? I will try that!

Comment: as long as your stylesheet is below the bootstraps stylesheet you just need to add inside your stylesheet